# Insert Angular directive into DOM from inside a Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My goal is to create an Angular module that displays popup dialog messages. This module contains a directive (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) containing the *internal logic* (and markup and styles). Plus there's a service (*factory*) which acts as an *API* that can be used by other services.

Now this service of course has an `openDialog()` function which should insert the dialog directive into the DOM and present it to the user.

All solutions to this problem I have found so far make use of the `$compile` function. But it needs `scope` as a parameter. In a service where there's no `scope` though. They only exist in `controller` or `link` functions.

The reason I chose this implementation is for separation of concerns (*directive's `link` and `controller` for internal usage, `factory` for external usage because it can be dependency injected*). I know I could pass the `scope` when calling the function like this:

```
popupDialogService.openDialog({ /* options */ }, $scope);
```

But I don't see the point. It doesn't feel right. What if I call that function from inside another service which doesn't use `scope` either?

Is there a way to easily put the directive into the DOM from inside the service function or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Another solution I'm thinking about is calling a function of the directive's `controller` from inside the directive's `factory`. Is that possible?

### Code

#### popupDialog.directive.js

```
angular.module('popupDialog').directive('popupDialog', directive);

function directive() {
    return { ... };
}
```

#### popupDialog.service.js

```
angular.module('popupDialog').factory('popupDialogService', factory);

function factory() {
    return { openDialog, closeDialog }; // *ES2015

    function openDialog(options) {
        // this function should put the `popupDialog` directive into the DOM
    }

    function closeDialog() {
        // and this one should remove it
    }
}
```

#### some.random.service.js

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('someRandomService', factory);

factory.$inject = ['popupDialogService'];
function factory(popupDialogService) {
    return { clickedButton };

    function clickedButton() {
        popupDialogService.openDialog({ /* options */ });
        // Sample implementation.
        // It shouldn't matter where this function is beeing called in the end.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I could pass the scope when calling the function ... And it doesn't feel right.

Well you anyway need scope for dialog HTML content, Angular needs to compile and render it in some scope, right? So you have to provide *scope* object for your template somehow.

I suggest you to take a look at popular modal implementations like they do it, for example Angular UI Bootstrap's [$modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) or this [simple one](https://github.com/dfsq/angular-google-tasks/blob/master/app/components/services/sModal.service.js) I was creating for my needs. The common pattern is passing scope parameter with modal initialization or use new child scope of the `$rootScope` for dialog. This is the most flexible way that should work for your both cases.

After all, it's not necessarily has to be real scope instance. You can even make your service accept plain javascript object and use it to extend new `$rootScope.$new()` object with.

Comment: Creating a new scope using the `$rootScope` is a nice solution that fits my needs right now. I understand that a directive needs a scope. But a dialog directive shouldn't care about its outer scope and have its own one instead. Your simple solution is a little to mixed up for my use. My dialog gets a little more complex and I don't want everything in a single service. That's why I go with a new scope for now. Thank you.